# How to compare two date values in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, ssms

I have a table with the date 2018 and date 2019 and here is my data.

```
select amount, date 
from TABLE1 
where date in (2018, 2019) and empid = 21120
```

It didn't work for me as the query says case when date =2019 then amount as my data above when date=2019 it will just show me the amount. This is what my result is:

```
Amount     Data         
9.67       2019     
21         2019         
6          2019        
9.56       2018     
42         2018         
7          2018
```

What is want it: the difference between the Amount for the two dates 2018 and 2019.

The above query gives me only one row of the amount for those dates.

My expected result is to find the difference in the amount between 2018 and 2019. Any ideas on how I could get the difference. I am trying self joining but any help is appreciated.

Ex: 2019 amount 9.67 -  2018 amount 9.56.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: To state the obvious, 2019 is not a date. It is a year. If your goal is to compare the rows you show 1 by 1, then you will need some set of columns that determines the order within each year for your comparison to succeed. If I had to guess, it appears there are no such columns and your question is based on the physical arrangement of rows you have included. Unfortunately, rows in a table are, by definition, unordered. That makes your goal impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be looking for conditional aggregation:

```
select
    sum(case when date = 2019 then amount else 0 end)
    - sum(case when date = 2018 then amount else 0 end) diff
from mytable
where empid = 21 and date in (2018, 2019)
```

The query gives you the difference between the total amount of 2019 and that of 2018 for the given employee.

This can be shortened a little:

```
select sum(case when date = 2019 then amount else -amount end) diff
from mytable
where empid = 21 and date in (2018, 2019)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do as

```
SELECT ABS(SUM(CASE WHEN Data = '2019' THEN Amount ELSE -Amount END)) Diff
FROM
(
  VALUES
  (9.67       , '2019'),     
  (21         , '2019'),         
  (6          , '2019'),        
  (9.56       , '2018'),     
  (42         , '2018'),         
  (7          , '2018') 
) T(Amount, Data)
WHERE Data IN ('2018', '2019')
      -- AND empid = 21120; Uncomment this when you run it against your table
```